# Loop through JSON and populate data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, foreach

I'm trying to iterate through JSON data and populate the content dynamically using jQuery.

1. First I do an Ajax request
2. Then I loop through the data and create the HTML tags dynamically

I create a div container with a class of "product-wrapper" for each JSON object (in this case 2 divs product-wrapper). As you can see on the example of my JSON data, each object has an array of objects "details".

From my second foreach loop - how can I populate the data of "details" within its appropriate "product-wrapper" div?

**JavaScript**

```
myApp.init = function(){

    var rates = {
        products: $('.products-container'),
        init: function(){
            rates.showRates();
        },
        showRates: function(){
            $.each(utils.rates, function(index, value){
                rates.products.append(
                    '<div class="product-wrapper">' +
                        '<div class="product-heading">' + value.name + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="product-details"></div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );

                $.each(value.details, function(i,val){
                    $('.product-details').append('<div class="detail-row">' +
                        '<div class="detail detail-balance">' + val.balance + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="detail detail-gross-rate">' + val.grossRate + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="detail detail-aer">' + val.aer + '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
                });
            });
        }
    };

    var utils = {
        rates: '',
        url: $('.business-interest-rates').attr('data-rates-json'),
        init: function(){
            utils.ajaxRequest();
        },
        ajaxRequest: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: utils.url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    utils.rates = data;

                    if($('#interest-rates').length > 0){
                        rates.init();
                    }
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    utils.init();
};
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name":"Australian dollar (AUD)",
        "currency":"AUD",
        "details":[
            {
                "balance": "1+",
                "grossRate": "1.700",
                "aer": "0.5"
            },
            {
                "balance": "500,000+",
                "grossRate": "2.100",
                "aer": "2.00"
            },
            {
                "balance": "1,500,000+",
                "grossRate": "2.450",
                "aer": "1.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"EURO (EU)",
        "currency":"EU",
        "details":[
            {
                "balance": "1+",
                "grossRate": "1.700",
                "aer": "1.50"
            },
            {
                "balance": "500,000+",
                "grossRate": "2.100",
                "aer": "2.20"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Either don't use a CSS class to append your stuff but unique ids, or first generate the whole HTML code (wrapper and details all together) in one step and then append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either don't use a CSS class to append your stuff but unique ids, or first generate the whole HTML code (wrapper and details all together) in one step and then append it.

```
// use unique IDs for appending
function () {
    $.each(utils.rates, function (index, value) {
        rates.products.append(
            '<div class="product-wrapper">' +
            '<div class="product-heading">' + value.name + '</div>' +
            '<div id="product-details-' + value.name + '"></div>' +
            '</div>'
        );

        $.each(value.details, function (i, val) {
            $('#product-details-' + value.name).append('<div class="detail-row">' +
                '<div class="detail detail-balance">' + val.balance + '</div>' +
                '<div class="detail detail-gross-rate">' + val.grossRate + '</div>' +
                '<div class="detail detail-aer">' + val.aer + '</div>' +
                '</div>');
        });
    });
}

// first generate all html code, then append
function () {
    $.each(utils.rates, function (index, value) {
        var html = '<div class="product-wrapper">' +
            '<div class="product-heading">' + value.name + '</div>' +
            '<div class="product-details">';
        $.each(value.details, function (i, val) {
            html += '<div class="detail-row">' +
                '<div class="detail detail-balance">' + val.balance + '</div>' +
                '<div class="detail detail-gross-rate">' + val.grossRate + '</div>' +
                '<div class="detail detail-aer">' + val.aer + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        });
        html += '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        rates.products.append(
            html
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It makes sense. In your opinion which solution seems to be the cleanest?

Comment: Both are fine in my opinion, my personal preference is to make whole HTML strings first and then add them to the DOM. Also: is there a reason you use the jQuery foreach-loop, instead of a regular for-loop? Native loop should be faster.

Comment: That's the solution I went for in the end. I Used jQuery foreach-loop mostly because it is simpler to write.

Comment: for(var i=0; i < value.details.length; i++){
        var val = value.details[i];
        // your code
    }
is simpler for me...

Comment: Also made that change. Thanks for the advice :)